# Python request.post gives 404

Tags: python, python-3.x, https

We have two microservices hosted on the same azure VM. Both are on HTTPS. One in java and another in python.
I am able to call python API from java but not able to call java API from python.

I am using python 3.7 and requests

```
backend_parsecv_response_url = config.BACKEND_BASE_URL + config.BACKEND_PARSECV_RESPONSE_SUBURL
logger.info("Calling backend API at: " + backend_parsecv_response_url)
requests.post(backend_parsecv_response_url, json=response, headers=headers)
```

but it gives 404 in logs. but I am able to hit API from postman will the same URL defined in config.

In logs its showing

**User-Agent**: Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/11.0.11)

Comment: Whats the actual output of the logging? (what string is `backend_parsecv_response_url` actually holding?)

Comment: it's our company's internal URL so I cant post it here

Comment: Have you set User-Agent in your headers? Also, try printing backend_parsecv_response_url before the call to requests.post() and make sure that you can resolve it

Comment: @AndyKnight I am printng URL in logs and it is correct i tried hitting same URL from postman. also added User-Agent in question

Comment: Is it an absolute path with a FQDN or a relative path? Can you manually access this path from the machine running the application?

Comment: It is FQDN like https://api.site.com/sub/url

Comment: @Jonathan Can you manually access this path from the machine running the application? what does this means?

Comment: @KetanSuthar Can you assure this absolute url is accessible in the network environment and not blocked by a Firewall or missing routing? If you get a 404 from calling an absolute path that does exist it's probably either the network environment or a [missing] server configuration

Comment: it is internal call only, we have third microservice in java which is able to call same API but not python service?